# iOS - How to resize elements on a screen depending on the amount of the elements

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit

So I am developing a game using Spritekit that uses a pyramid of Sprites (let's say circles for a simple instance). The user can choose the amount of rows of sprites they would like to have in the game. The sprites are to form a pyramid, so if you have 1 row, you have 1 sprite node. It increases by 2 the farther down you go (the more rows you choose) - creating the pyramid shape. So if a user picked 3 rows, the game board would look like this:
    
                                            `O
                                          O O O
                                        O O O O O`

However, when it gets to 5 rows, it loses its pyramid shape because the screen is only so wide and it has to fit all the elements onto the screen (elements are more smushed together in rows further down).

My question is, to fix this issue, what would I have to do to make the pyramid resize and change its spacing between elements depending on how many rows are chosen? Would I have to multiply the spacing by a certain factor? I have also heard of people adding layers onto the screen - maybe drawing the sprites in some sort of container so that it always resizes the pyramid to fit the screen without skewing the pyramid shape?

Comment: hey there, did my answer help you? If not, let me know so I can try to update it for you.

Comment: @Fluidity I could not get it to work. It was doing the same thing that my code was doing (making the pyramid shape rounder as it got to the bottom rows). Cannot figure out how to retain the shape of the pyramid and resize it as a whole when it gets too large to fit screen

Answer (score 0):

Your idea is correct! Make a `SKNode` container, then update it's `.size` property, or do `.setScale`.

(not at xcode right now, pardon if not 100%)

```
// Say that our scene's size is 400x400:
let bkg = SKShapeNode(rectangleOfSize: self.size)
bkg.addChild(firstSprite)
bkg.addChild(secondSprite) // And so on...

// Find the farthest point in bkg:
var farthestX = CGFloat(0)
for node in bkg.children {
  if node.position.x + node.frame.size.width / 2 > farthestX {
    farthestX = node.position.x + node.frame.size.width / 2
  }
}

// Do math to resize the bkg:
if self.size.width < farthestX {
  let scaler = self.size.width / farthestX
  bkg.setScale(scaler)
}
```

This should work, or at least the general idea should work... You would want to check for Y values and Height as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily compute a symmetrical size proportional to the number of rows and resize your sprites accordingly. This is my idea in pseudocode:

```
 let computedSize = deviceWidth/(2*(rows-1) + 1)

 for sprite in sprites {

     sprite.size.width = computedSize
     sprite.size.height = computedSize


 }
```